# pass value from element inside ngFor to Service

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a component which iterates through an array of areas which all have unique id's. When you click the button it opens a dialog which contains a iframe which listens to an eventlistener and retrieves data as JSON and sends it via post to a INSERT method in my ASP.NET CORE API.

I'm now also trying to send the id of the area and right now I only pass it as a paramter on the openDialog function.

planner.component.html

```js
<div *ngFor="let area of areas">
 <div class="area-container">
  {{area.areaId}}
  <button (click)="openDialog(area.areaId)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded">+</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

planner.component.ts

The dialog opens with the iframe and right now only logs the id of the area.

```js
 openDialog(id: number) {
    let dialogref = this.dialog.open(IframeComponent, {
      width: '120vh'
    });
    console.log({areaId:id}) // like this {areaId: 20}
    this.plannerService.getData(this.id);
    dialogref.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog closed: ${result}`);
      this.dialogresult = result;
    })
  }
```

in the service i have a eventListener which stores data from the iframe and sends it to my ASP.NET Core API as JSON

You can see here that I'm trying to send in an id but i don't know how to get the value from the planner.component which makes it undefined.

.planner.service.ts

```js
getData(id: number) {
    window.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
      let data = JSON.parse(e.data)
      console.log(data);
      console.log({areaId: id})
      this.createResource(data, id).subscribe(data => this.resources.push(data));
      }, false);
  }
```

data from iframe as JSON

```
{id: 282970, title: "page 1", description: "", thumbnail: "https://site/image/resourc…umbnail?guid=a0b67c13-ead4-49e0-a576-b4c8be1491b2", url: "https://site/l/show.html#PZWQz", …}
description: ""
guid: "a0b67c13-ead4-49e0-a576-b4c8be1491b2"
id: 282970
thumbnail: "https://site/image/resourcethumbnail?guid=a0b67c13-ead4-49e0-a576-b4c8be1491b2"
title: "page 1"
url: "https://site/l/show.html#PZWQz"

{areaId: undefined}
```

the question is how can a pass the value of the areaId inside the planner.component (which now only gets logged) to my service method so that i can pass it to my API?

Comment: Have you injected your service inside the component?

Comment: Where do you call `PlannerService.getData(id)`??

Comment: @AsimHashmi Yes i have injected it and try to use it in the openDialog method.

Comment: @IkennaAnthonyOkafor I'm calling it in my openDialog method under the console.log

Comment: @därko You should be doing `this.plannerService.getData(id);` or set `this.id = id;` before `this.plannerService.getData(this.id);`

Comment: @IkennaAnthonyOkafor setting this.id = id before did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component, you can inject your `planner` service and call its method

Assuming your service name is `PlannerService`

You component contructor would be like this:

```
constructor(private plannerService: PlannerService) {

}
```

And then in your method you can do this:

```
openDialog(id: number) {
    let dialogref = this.dialog.open(IframeComponent, {
      width: '120vh'
    });
    console.log({areaId:id}) // like this {areaId: 20}
    this.plannerService.getData(id) <-- here id is the parameter you want to send
    dialogref.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog closed: ${result}`);
      this.dialogresult = result;
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i got it to work with this answer and setting
 this.id = id before as Ikenna commented!

Comment: Try logging the `id` parameter in your `getData()` method before the listener and then in the listener function

Comment: I don't think that you need to set `this.id` if you just pass `id` param instead of `this.id` to `getData` like `this.plannerService.getData(id)` as I did in my answer :)